# How to get child json items in ng-options

Tags: angularjs

Below is my data

```
This.dynamicCmbItems = [{
                id: 1,
                label: 'aLabel',
                subItem: [
                    {
                        name: 'aSubItem1'
                    },
                     {
                         name: 'aSubItem2'
                     },
                      {
                          name: 'aSubItem3'
                      }
                ]
            }, {
                id: 2,
                label: 'bLabel',
                subItem: [{ name: 'bSubItem' }]
            }];
```

I want to display `vm.dynamicCmbItems.subItem` in dropdown. I have written code like this

```
 <select ng-options="item.name for item in vm.dynamicCmbItems.subItem " ng-model="vm.selected"></select>
```

but this is not working.

Comment: can you please put the code you tried here?  it helps with trying to find out what might have gone awry.

Comment: I have edited my post....I have posted html code which I tried

Answer (score 0):

Your json in an array so you must mention number of index that you want repeat like below:
dynamicCmbItems[$index].subitems

Or

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="item in dynamicCmbItems>
 <input type="select" data-ng-options="subitems.name as subitems.name for subitems in item.subItem">
```

Comment: your code will create 2 dropdowns i.e, it will create number of dropdowns as it loops dynamicCmbItems evrytime

Comment: Ok, you may need merge subitems in an areay (do it in controller) before use in ngRepeat.